# How to clean a single Android lunch target only?

Tags: android, android-source

I've built two lunch targets:

- aosp_x86_64-eng
- sdk_phone_x86_64-eng

I want to clean the second target only. It took me 3 days to build the first target.

At [this documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building?hl=en#build-the-code) it says about **m clean**:

> deletes all of the output and intermediate files for this configuration. This is the same as `rm -rf out/.`

As you see the documentation is contradictory. It says "for this configuration" which was fine for my case. But it also says "This is the same as rm -rf out/". And the folder "out" is the build folder for **all** lunch targets.

So does **m clean** clean the current lunch target only or what is the right command?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for editing the question but it's indeed called lunch.

Answer (score 1):

You should lunch sdk_phone_x86_64-eng again, then exuecute "make [installclean](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:build/soong/ui/build/cleanbuild.go;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=81?q=installclean&gsn=installClean&gs=KYTHE%3A%2F%2Fkythe%3A%2F%2Fandroid.googlesource.com%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject%2Fmain%2F%2Fmain%3Flang%3Dgo%3Fpath%3Dbuild%2Fsoong%2Fui%2Fbuild%23func%2520installClean)". It will deletes all of the installed files for the target.

Comment: Another shortcut what I used to use is `rm -rf $OUT`